# Hide Views from View List

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a plugin that fires on PreOperation of RetrieveMultiple and adds a query condition that the view name does not begin with HIDDEN_ . In the web client this works perfectly. In my on prem Outlook client (for my sandbox) it also works perfectly. However when I am using Outlook 2010 with an online environment it still displays the hidden view in the drop down (but not if you open an advanced find).

On top of this issue I also am unable to prefix my dashboard views with HIDDEN_. If i do then the dashboards display no information. I haven't been able to get it to work properly with the dashboard views, but I need to hide them as I have two entities that have a dozen views each that are only used for the dashboards.

In short these are the two questions:
1. How do I hide views for an online 2011 environment in the outlook client?
2. How do I hide the dashboard views and still use them for the purpose of creating dashboards?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your plugin on the PreValidation step.

Of course, all clients should show exact similar behaviour, so to me it seems you have found a bug.